# Example for Simple Bayes Naive Classifier with matrices

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian

I understood the general formula:

```
P(i | x) =  (p(i)p(x|i))/(sum(p(j)(p(x|j))
```

But I cannot successfully apply it to this exercise:

*Consider the data sets for two classes X1 = {(0,0)} and X2 = {(1,0), (0,1)}. Which classification probabilities will a naive Bayes classifier produce for the feature vector (0,0)?*

I can't understand what **p(1)** and **p((0,0)|1)** would be in this case.

Comment: There are plenty of **books** and tutorials that explain the Naive Bayes Classificator. Why don't you **read the explanations given by *professional* teachers** instead of expecing some random internet user to explain your homework to you?

Comment: Because all the books and "explanations given by professional teachers" use different cases, like real world ones (illness, email spams). I cannot apply it to this matrix example.

Comment: I actually agree the question isn't very well written. I would guess X1 are the training examples for category 1, and X2 the examples for category 2. This makes p(1) the prior probability of category 1 and p((0,0)|1) the likelihood. And I'm guessing this should have a homework tag

Comment: There is no matrix in your question. X1 contains one example `(x,y)`: `(0,0)` and `X2` contains *two training examples*. I see training data with 2 classes (X1 and X2), 3 instances total, and 2 attributes.
I have to agree that the question is using a different syntax than most books, but so what. I would *again* use a different syntax in an answer.

Comment: It's not homework, I am prepairing for an exam and this was given as example with the solution **p(1 | (0,0)) = 2/3** .. I wanted just to figure how to get that answer

Answer (score 0):

The naive Bayes classifier is not the Bayes formula! Those are two completely different concepts!

Comment: Not really. The naive Bayes classifier boils down to computing the Bayes formula a few times, then choosing the maximum.

Comment: Yes it is used in the naive Bayes computations but it is just a simple computational tool and not a probabilistic model like the naive Bayes itself. Those are two different _concepts_ the formula and the model. Just like when I calculate the hydrogen atom spectrum using the Schrodinger equation : I am solving a differential equation but the tool I am using for the solution (whatever mathematical tool that is) is not the model what I am solving.